# Push all objects from array of objects to another array of objects

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I am getting some data from the backend and I need to connect it to the frontend. It comes as an array of objects. My current code only returns the last object from the array:

```js
// @flow
import AnyAction from "redux";
import { ActionTypes } from "./../constants";
import type { Block } from "./types";

const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    blocks: []
};

const someReduceFunction = () => {};

export default function Blocks(state: Block[] = initialState, action: AnyAction): Block[] {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.GET_BLOCKS_REQUEST:
            return state;
        case ActionTypes.GET_BLOCKS_SUCCESS:
            console.log(action.res);
            console.log(Object.assign({}, state.blocks, ...Object.values(action.res)));
            return Object.assign({}, state.blocks, ...Object.values(action.res));
        case ActionTypes.GET_BLOCKS_FAILURE:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, state.blocks` probably meant to just have `state` there as otherwise you are basically changing an array object to a plain object. Eg going from `[2,3]` to `{"0":2,"1":3,"length":2}` not to mention changing the structure from what you defined in the initial state

Comment: Does that even compile? `state: Block[] = initialState` looks weird and I'd also not expect that return type of the reducer... I guess you would want to return something like `{fetching: false, blocks: action.res.blocks}` (depending on how your action looks like) or `{fetching: false, blocks: [...state.blocks, ...action.res.blocks]}` in the success case.

Comment: @MichaelH. probably typescript, with a default parameter, and op simply didnt tag it

Comment: @PatrickEvans having just `state` would result in returning  ```Object {
  "blocks": Array [],
  "fetching": false,
  "id": 4,
  "courses": null,
  "title": null,
  "description": null,
  "start": null,
  "locked": false
}```
But I need this data (from `id` to `locked`) in my `blocks` array inside state.